# How can resolve **Uncaught Reference Error: io is not defined at client.js:1:16** error?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, backend, nodemon

I am trying to create a real time chat app project using node and socket but when I try to run this using nodemon then it gives me error like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at client.js:1:16
```

and

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

plz help me to get out from this frustration.
here are respective code:-

```
const express=require("express");

const http=require("http");

const app=express();

const server=http.createServer(app);

const io=require("socket.io")(server)

app.get("/",function (req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"))

io.on("connection",(socket)=> {
    console.log('Connected');

})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function(){
    console.log('Running....');
})
```

code at client.js:-

```
const socket = io()
let name;
let textarea=document.querySelector("#textarea");
let msgArea=document.querySelector(".mssg_area");
do{
    name = prompt("what do your friends call you?");
}while(!name);

textarea.addEventListener("keyup",function (e) {
    if(e.key==="Enter"){
        sendMessage(e.target.value);
    }
})

function sendMessage(message) {
    let msg={
        user:name,
        message:message
    }
    appendMessage(msg,"outgoing")
}

function appendMessage(msg,type) {
    let mainDiv=document.createElement("div")
    let className=type
    mainDiv.classList.add(className,"message")

    let markUp=`
    <h4>${msg.user}</h4>
    <p>${msg.message}</p>
    `
    mainDiv.innerHTML=markUp
    msgArea.appendChild(mainDiv)
}
```

It would be very helpful to me if you resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

on the client side you should install `socket.io-client` not `socket.io`

[Client Api](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/)

Answer (score 1):

I had been fiddling around with this kind of problem for weeks. I was not able to solve this problem and it had been stressing me out. But Alas, I finally found the solution by searching in several sources. So I am going to tell the step by step process on how to fix it.

1. First and foremost, install the **socket.io** package by doing in terminal (`npm install socket.io`)
2. Second, type `npm install nodemon`
3. Third, type `npm init --y`to get the file **package.json**. Then, in the **package.json**, at `"scripts": {}`, write `"devStart": "nodemon server.js"` (so you don't have to re-run the code in the server) and also `"start": "node server.js"`. Then, at `"main":` , type `"main": "server.js"`
4. Now, in your **script.js**, you forgot to put the link in `io()` as an argument.
   For instance, you can do:

   ```
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3000'); //You need to pass in the localhost:3000
    let name;
    let textarea=document.querySelector("#textarea");
    let msgArea=document.querySelector(".mssg_area");
    do{
        name = prompt("what do your friends call you?");
    }while(!name);
   ```

   This will tell the server to access the webpage in localhost:3000
5. Then, in the server.js, import the module **socket.io** by doing:

   ```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
   ```

which you did correctly.

But, in the last part of your code, you should do:

```
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function(){
    console.log('Running....');
    })
```

instead of: `app.listen()`

6. Now, this is the most confusing part. This is where the error kicks in. The reason why we get the Error:

   ```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at client.js:1:16
   ```

   is because we haven't imported/require the module for the socket.io in the client.js. In order to do that, we first need to get the module from the node_modules folder. So:

- Scroll and Find the socket.io module in the node_modules folder in VSCode ( you should see socket.io in it)
- Make a new folder in your directory/folder that has your client.js and server.js called **public**
- Then copy or move the file/module to the new folder **public**
- Now, go to your HTML file and in the `<body>` type the following:

  ```
    <body>
    <script src="public/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
    </body>
  ```

  Now, I might be wrong here since people do the other way that is(Doesn't work for me and probably you):

  ```
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
  ```

  which, in my case, doesn't work for me because there is no such socket.io module in localhost/website. But, it probably doesn't work for me since I am using windows. So, if the first `<script>` tag I gave you didn't work, then you can try this one.

The point what I'm trying to tell you is, you need to import/require the socket.io module for the client.js in order for it to work. Otherwise, it will give that Unreferenced Error. Doing `const io = require("socket.io")` in client-side javascript won't work. You have to import it using `<script>` tag in the body. Or by doing `<script defer src="...">` in the `head`.

So after all of this, it should work. Go to your server.js and run the server at localhost:3000. Go to Chrome(or other sites) and type localhost:3000

If the error is still there, then maybe the path to your **public** folder with the **socket.io** module is wrong OR I am wrong.

If you get the CORS error:

```
    const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin, "*" //Or type your localhost or link
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
    });
```

you can go to [info on socket.io Cors](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/) for more info.

Or install the cors module by doing `npm install cors`

Apologies if I did something wrong or for my broken English. I am terribly sorry as this is my first ever StackOverFlow answer and I couldn't just let this question go to rest. I must answer as I have the viable solution for it. So Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, you have installed socket.io module. If not installed, install this by using command -
npm install socket.io

Comment: I have reinstalled socket.io but there is no effect !!

Comment: Your code has no issue.. seems to be client.js is not perfectly included in server file.

Comment: so how can I do that?

Comment: File which you running in the browser, there socket.io.js and client.js file should be included - [<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>]
    [<script src="/js/client.js"></script>]

Comment: If you are using express, then you didn't need to create server using http. So, instead of -
     const server=http.createServer(app);

It could be -
     const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function(){
             console.log('Running....');
     })